# Show that a sequence can't be longer than $p+q-d$ when the product of every consecutive subsequence of length $p$ is $<1$ and $q$ products are $>1$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, contest-math

This problem is from Engels Problem solving strategies. A p-product refers to a subsequence containing $p$ terms, that are picked consecutively and multiplied. I don't see what he is referring to when he says we can use logarithms here.

[image]

Comment: Did he possibly previously present another problem which was about $p$-sums $<0$ and $q$-sums $>0$ (sums of consecutive $p$ or $q$ numbers, *added*)? Maybe he wants to demonstrate how using logarithms can reduce this problem to *that* problem?

Comment: you're right, $p-$sums were the previous problem.  I don't, however, see how to use logarithms to make the problem about $p$-products equivalent

Comment: If your sequence is $(x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, take another sequence $(\log x_1, \log x_2,\ldots,\log x_n)$ and notice that it satisfies the conditions of that previous problem. ($x_kx_{k+1}\cdots x_{k+p-1}<1$ if and only if $\log(x_kx_{k+1}\cdots x_{k+p-1})=\log x_k+\log x_{k+1}+\ldots+\log_{k+p-1}<0$).

Comment: For context, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3537664/700480

Comment: @StinkingBishop Great!

Comment: What is $d$ in your question?